# How to read certain data from the Text file in C

Tags: c, file, keyword, printf

Here is my problem, i have to read a certain data from the Text file. How?

For example: "test1.txt" has some data like

IEEEXtreme 2008 edition is going to take place on March 8th 2008

And i have "keyword.txt" with:

2008 place

I have to read text from the word "2008" upto "place" word.

////////////////////////////////////////////

let's make this simple...
can you help me with this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="This is a simple string";

  char * p1,* p2;

  p1 = strstr(str,"is");
  p2 = strstr(str,"string");


  puts (str);
  system("Pause");
  return 0;
}
```

i wan't to make this only read from is to string.

Comment: What have you worked out so far?

Comment: i will pull out my code, but it might be a bit bad... if you find an easy way feel free to post.

Comment: Please share the code.

Comment: +1 Posting code and learning from mistakes are part of SO culture

Answer (score 0):

Read the line (`fgets`) (store in `p`) then `strstr` in `p` for "2008" (store in `p1`) and another one for "place" (store in `p2`), between them (from `p1 + strlen("2008")` till `p2`) is what you need ...

**EDIT after seeing the source (code review :P not algorithm review)**

in `ler_pc`:

1. do not return the local variable, instead allocate memory and return that (`malloc`, `calloc`) (Do not forget to free it (at the caller side) when done with it)
2. if the file is longer than 60 bytes possibly you will have a crash in your application. Put a maximum size to the line you want to read.
3. If you use `calloc` to allocate the memory, no need to put a terminator zero byte. or ... `char str[60] = {0}` might work too, depending on your compiler

in `ler_frases`

1. possibly, you want the `p1[aux] = '\0'` out of the loops, it makes no sense to set it to zero every time (or see number 3. from above). Same for `p2`...
2. For the first time, in `strcmp(palavra, p1)` `palavra` is not initialized, so you don't know what's in there :( Possibly you want a `do ... while` loop, not a while.
3. out of formaility, `strcmp(palavra, p1) == 0` can be written as `!strcmp(palavra, p1)`
4. do not allocate `excerto` at the beginning. Makes no sense since you are not using it.
5. `while ((cntrl = 1)` possibly you meant `==` (same for the zero part)
6. `sizeof(excerto)` is always the size of a pointer, not the length of the string. `strlen()` gives you the length of the string.

in `main`

1. In case you run this on linux, `pause` != `PAUSE` != `Pause` when comes about `system`.
2. You happily run the application even if the files are not found :(

generally:

1. Please use a consistent indentation. It will save you from a lot of bugs and will make people to want to read your code.
2. Always free what you allocate :)

**Second edit for the second source**

For this specific case:

`p1 = strstr(str,"is");` will return a pointer which will point to the first `is` in the string... ie: the 3rd character ("This" contains "is") ... so possibly you want `" is"`

`p2 = strstr(str,"string");` will give you the pointer pointing to string.

Now you need to do something like:

```
/* allocate enough memory for the string between " is" and "string" */
size_t len = p2 - p1 + strlen(" is") + 1;
char* between = (char*)(calloc(len, sizeof(char));

/* and copy out the string from the original*/
strncpy(between, p1 + strlen(" is"), len);
```

so now in `between` you have the required string (I hope I understood correctly what you wanted).

PS: put back the original code, others might learn from it.

Comment: while( ( p = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
      
   p1= strstr(p,"2008")
   p2= strstr(p,"2009")
   printf("%c",);
          printf("\n");

it's something like this?

Comment: fgets, not fgetc, but geneally more or less similar.